# Maintaining a user-specified order of elements in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a tad different from rememebering say sort-by-date or sort-by-alphabet.  I have a list of Items, that I'd like to allow the User to rearrange.  More importantly, I'd like to remember that order.  How would I do this?

Comment: How would you implement how the user arranges them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [acts_as_list act](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Acts/List/ClassMethods.html#M000680). Put `acts_as_list` in your model, add the field "`position`", which is an `integer`, to the table you want to sort, and create the new actions for the different sorts.

The documentation for acts_as_list that I linked to has code examples, but if you need more help, leave a comment and I'll edit this.

Comment: If each user can access the same object you would need a mapping-class between those. Example: `User <- FavoriteShopItem -> ShopItem` and `acts_as_list` on `FavoriteShopItem`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a commment/addition to the accepted answer above.

acts_as_list is not designed for anything beyond a prototype, and out of the box it does not handle concurrency or data integrity at all. At the very least, you must set your isolation level to serializable! Here's a [short screen cast](http://rhnh.net/2010/06/30/acts-as-list-will-break-in-production) with more information, and some workarounds.

Also, the correct link is github.com/rails/acts_as_list

Answer (score 0):

check out https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model, a better performing rewrite of acts_as_list.

This article shows you how to put it all together using jquery ui on the frontend: http://benw.me/posts/sortable-bootstrap-tables/